# Rolling 7 Day Sum grouped by date and unique ID

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyr

I am using workload data to compute 3 metrics - `Daily`, `7-Day rolling` (sum of last 7 days) `28-Day Rolling Average`(sum of last 28 days/4).

I have been able to compute by `Daily` but I need my `7-Day rolling` and `28-Day Rolling Average` and am having some trouble.  I have 17 unique ID's for each date (dates range from `2018-08-09` to `2018-12-15`).

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
library(tidyverse)
library(zoo)

Post_Practice <- read.csv("post.csv", stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
Post_Data <- Post_Practice[, 1:3]
DailyLoad <- Post_Data %>% 
  group_by(Date, Name) %>% 
  transmute(Daily = sum(DayLoad)) %>% 
  distinct(Date, Name, .keep_all = TRUE) %>% 
  mutate('7-day' = rollapply(Daily, 7, sum, na.rm = TRUE, partial = TRUE))
```

Input:

```
  Date              Name       DayLoad
2018-08-09       Athlete 1    273.92000
2018-08-09       Athlete 2    351.16000
2018-08-09       Athlete 3    307.97000
2018-08-09       Athlete 1    434.20000
2018-08-09       Athlete 2    605.92000
2018-08-09       Athlete 3    432.87000
```

Input looks like this all the way to `2018-12-15`.  Some dates have multiples of data (like above) and some only have one entry.

This code produces the `7-day` column but it shows the same number as the `Daily` ie:

```
   Date       Name                Daily   7-day
   <chr>      <chr>               <dbl>   <dbl>
 1 2018-08-09 Athlete 1           708.    708.
 2 2018-08-09 Athlete 2           957.    957.
 3 2018-08-09 Athlete 3           741.    741.
```

The goal is to have final table (ie 7 days later) look like this:

```
   Date       Name                Daily   7-day
   <chr>      <chr>               <dbl>   <dbl>
 1 2018-08-15 Athlete 1           413.    3693.
 2 2018-08-15 Athlete 2           502.    4348.
 3 2018-08-15 Athlete 3           490.    4007.
```

Where the `Daily` is the sum of that specific date and the `7-Day`is the sum of the last 7 dates for that specific unique ID.

Comment: This isn't clear to me. Where does the 2018-08-09 come from?  Three are not 7 dates so what is meant by taking the rolling sum of 7 days? How do the numbers in the expected output relate to the input?

Answer (score 1):

The help file for rollsum says:

> The default methods of rollmean and rollsum do not handle inputs that
>   contain NAs.

Use `rollapplyr(x, width, sum, na.rm = TRUE)` to exclude NAs in the input from the sum.  Note the `r` at the end of `rollapplyr` to specify right alignment.

Also note the `partial=TRUE` argument can be used if you want partial sums at the beginning rather than NAs.

Comment: Edited code above to show using `rollapplyr`.  My `7-day` column is now just showing the same value as my `Daily` column instead of the 7 day sum for that individual

Comment: The question only shows the output but not the input. All questions to SO should have *complete* minimal and verifiable code examples. Maybe the error is that you have grouped by Date so that there is only one row per group.

Comment: Hope my edits above are more complete.  Essentially each individual date will have its own input, but what I am struggling with is finding a 7-day rolling sum for each athlete.